# Retrofit 2: No virtual method newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;) NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am searching for this error whole internet, but yet, only one stackoverflow entry with no answer or comment. 
I am trying to use Retrofit 2. It is my first time using it. Here are my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

I exclued any OkHttp libraries as Retrofit already uses it.

This is my request interface:

```
public interface LoginService {
    @POST(HTTPService.AUTHENTICATIO_URL)
    Call<User> login();
}
```

Next: my Service generator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

public static final String API_BASE_URL = HTTPService.BASE_URL;

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password, String roleId) {
    if (username != null && password != null) {
        String credentials = username+":"+password+":"+roleId;
        final String basic =
                "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", basic)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .method(original.method(), original.body());

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        });
    }

    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

And next: where I make the request:

```
 @Override
public void loadData(DataSource.LoadJsonCallback loadJsonCallback) {
    String login = mUser.getLogin();
    String password = mUser.getPassword();
    LoginService loginService =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, login, password, "");
    Call<User> call = loginService.login();
    String a = call.request().url().toString();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            try {
                loadJsonCallback.onTasksLoaded(response.body());
                User a = response.body();
                mUser = getDataFromJson("");
                if (mUser != null) {
                    mUser.setPassword(password);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            loadJsonCallback.onDataNotAvailable(t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

So, I get this exception, that I cannot find anywhere:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader; in class Lcom/google/gson/Gson; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.gson.Gson' appears in /data/app/org.ucomplex.ucomplex-2/base.apk)
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I've seen a couple of questions on this.  The error implies the code is being linked against an older version of Gson.  Your dependencies look okay to me.  Were you previously using an older version of Gson?  Have you tried cleaning your project and rebuilding?

Comment: @iagreen, lol that was it for me :D, you are the man!

Comment: Sadly, did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started using the newer versions:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

And the error disappeared.